# Updating total record from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `table1` with the column of `item_id, item_name` and `total_sold`. In table two are fields `id,item_name,pk_item_id`. Insertions are made in table two and i want to count the total number of items in `table 2` and update it to the `total_sold` column in `table1`. So at the end it will update every item in `table1` with the total number of items inserted in `table2`

can anyone help me with an update script? below is my incomplete update script

```
UPDATE table1

    SET table1.total_sold = (select COUNT(table2.item) from table2)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? that would break a very basic concept in RDB Normalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to relate the two tables.   I assume they are related on `Table1.Item_id=Table2.pk_item_id`:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET table1.total_sold = (
      select COUNT(table2.item) 
      from table2
      WHERE table2.pk_item_id=table1.item_id
)
```